# Not able to install open jdk 8 172 version on linux

Tags: java, java-8

On my development server I am not able to install specific version (172) of openjdk 8.

I tried to install using aptitude but not able to install it.

`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless=8u172-b01-2`

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '8u172-b01-2' for 'openjdk-8-jre-headless' was not found

Comment: The question would be more on-topic on the [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or the [ServerFault SE](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **aptitude** while installing

```
sudo aptitude install openjdk-8-jre-headless=8u172-b01-2
```

It was already asked, check [install exact version of openjdk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987748/install-exact-version-of-openjdk?rq=1) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: it is not working now . https://askubuntu.com/questions/987748/install-exact-version-of-openjdk?rq=1